# How to use for loop to print strings in fixed views

Tags: java, android, for-loop, if-statement

I know the question might sounds weird `(feel free to edit the title)`, but what I want to accomplish basically is this:

Let's say that I have a list of 4 strings:

```
ArrayList<String> carList= new ArrayList<>;
 carList.add("BMW");
 carList.add("GMC");
 carList.add("KIA");
 carList.add("Honda");
```

I want now to print 3 of the list items into 3 textviews, the fourth item will be excluded for some reason and its position is known.

```
int excludedIndex = 2; //for example.

for (int i = 0; i < carList.size(); i++) {
      if (i != excludedIndex) {
        textView_1.setText(carList.get(i));  // here it will put (BMW) in tv1
        textView_2.setText(carList.get(??)); // here it should put (GMC) in tv2
        textView_3.setText(carList.get(??)); // here it should put (Honda) in tv3
       }
    }
```

Comment: java is not javascript. you are setting the index, not the elements of your list. you don't need a loop there. just textView_1.setText(carList.get(0)); will do

Comment: Why not a recyclerview? remove the item to be hidden from list before setting the adapter

Comment: @Stultuske sorry about that. This's just an example, but in fact the list size isn't known and the `excludedIndex` isn't fixed and it can't be changed.

Comment: @AlaaAbuZarifa in that case, you need the loop, but the way to work remains the same. BTW, either it isn't fixed, or it can be changed. saying "it isn't fixed and it can't be changed" makes very little sense

Comment: @Stultuske yeah, I meant it's not fixed.

Comment: @AlaaAbuZarifa then still it's not that difficult. what is the part you are having trouble with exactly?

Comment: @Stultuske What I want is setting the textviews with a text from the list items in order, but excluding the item of the `excludedIndex ` position.

Comment: @AlaaAbuZarifa yes, I understand that, but with the information already given, what is it stopping you from implementing that?

Comment: did you see the example in the question..! you would see where I'm stuck.

Comment: @GhostCat  of course, sorry for taking so long.

Comment: Never mind. It is always a pleasure to receive +25 out of the blue, for work long done ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are asking: how do I *map* elements of a list (identified by their index) to a certain text field. And that sentence already contains one possible solution - by using a `Map<Integer, TextView>` that knows which text view should be used for which index.

As in:

```
Map<Integer, TextView> viewsByIndex = ...
for (int i = ... ) {
  if (viewsByIndex.containsKey(i)) {
     viewsByIndex.get(i).setText(listItem(i));
```

The above code isn't compiled/checked - it is rather meant as inspiration/pseudo code showing how one could solve this in an elegant way.

Comment: it would work kinda.. but in my case it won't be enough, because if the textview of the `excludedIndex` will just be empty because its index matches the the key of the a certain textview.

Comment: @AlaaAbuZarifa all you need more than the solution provided by GhostCat, is a flag that states you'll need to add 1 to the index as soon as the flag is true, and it should be set to true once you are on your excludedIndex

Comment: @AlaaAbuZarifa I think you didn't get my solution. You dont have to **exclude** anything. Because you can ask the map whether an index is known or not. If the map doesn't know the index, then it is automatically excluded!

Comment: oh, I get it now. Anyhow I solve it using recyclerview. but I guess ur slolation is better.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use for loop

```
ArrayList<String> carList= new ArrayList<>();
carList.add("BMW");
carList.add("GMC");
carList.add("KIA");
carList.add("Honda");


 textView_1.setText(carList.get(0));  // here it will put (BMW) in tv1
 textView_2.setText(carList.get(1)); // here it should put (GMC) in tv2
 textView_3.setText(carList.get(3)); // here it should put (Honda) in tv3
```

Comment: This's just an example, but in fact the list size isn't known and the `excludedIndex` isn't fixed and it can't be changed. so a loop is needed.

Comment: so you have to take a recycler view

Comment: take a TextView inside the row of recycler view. & pass the array to the recycler view Adapter & put a if else condition for exclusion.